# On Raspberry Pi / cannot access all computers in network

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, debian, 64-bit, raspberry-pi

I am a bit confuse here. I am not able to access or even ping my Tasmota devices on my raspberry pie. That said, I am able to ping my proxmox servers from my pie.

I can ping my tasmota devices from my other pcs on the same network.  Oddly, I cannot initially ping these devices from any VMs or CTs but if I leave it pinging for a long time, sometimes it does reach the device.  (From the other PCs, pinging works every time.)

Here is the output of ping

from my pi to server

```
pi@smarthome:~ $ ping 192.168.1.45
PING 192.168.1.45 (192.168.1.45) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.45: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.520 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.45: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.411 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.45: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.448 ms
```

from my pi to tasmota device

```
pi@smarthome:~ $ ping 192.168.1.91
PING 192.168.1.91 (192.168.1.91) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.197 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.197 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Comment: Applying blockquotes on the ping results makes them more readable. Could you please clarify a little... what's exactly the role fo the Pi, and what's the role of the server? How does the Pi connect to the server? How do the Tasmota devices connect? Can the server ping the Tasmota devices? You've tagged this with "wireless-networking", so is there a wireless router or AP somewhere, or do you use ad-hoc networking? What's the WiFi - 2.4Ghz or 5Ghz? Do wireless devices maintain stable connection to the WiFi/AP? Please don't answer in comments, but rather update the question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.